# height: max-content; not working on parent div

Tags: css

```html
<body onload="load_animes()">
    <div class="head">
        <!-- <h1 id="head_title">Hello</h1> -->
        
        <img src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/7206d8a9-d46d-4479-b47a-8cf6d05bc830/d7zzah3-c53850a6-5d66-437b-a581-99d84fea1923.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3sicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvNzIwNmQ4YTktZDQ2ZC00NDc5LWI0N2EtOGNmNmQwNWJjODMwXC9kN3p6YWgzLWM1Mzg1MGE2LTVkNjYtNDM3Yi1hNTgxLTk5ZDg0ZmVhMTkyMy5wbmcifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6ZmlsZS5kb3dubG9hZCJdfQ.oSQAAL-K2KoIhZJTBTpnvqqcy2cC8QjmgsUwlsS-0Uk" id="head_bg">

        <h1 id="desc">
            This is a website where I post my shitty reviews about anime that I have watched. All anime are sorted based on the first alphabet of their names
        </h1>

        <h1 id="note">
            <strong>Note:</strong> There will be spoilers in my reviews
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="view">
        <div id="layer"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <h1 id="view_title"></h1>
            <h2 id="view_genres"></h2>
            <p id="view_note">Note: I don't assign the genres according to MAL, I assign the genres based on my own opinion</p>
            <h3 id="view_rating"></h3>
            <h4 id="view_review"></h4>
            <button id="back" onclick="back()">Back To List</button>
            <img id="view_img">
        </div>
    </div>
```

my style:

```css
body {
    background-color: #28282B;
    /* background-image: url("img_tree.gif"); */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}

*{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#view{
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: max-content;
    margin: -8px;
}

#view #layer {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: max-content;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

#view div {
    position: absolute;
}

#view #view_title{
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2%;

    z-index: 1;
}

#view #view_genres{
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#view #view_note{
    color: rgb(243, 226, 226);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#view #view_rating{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: 'open sans',arial,sans-serif;
}

#view #view_review{
    background-color: #18181a;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border-radius: 5px;

    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

#view #view_img{
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 70%;

    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#view #back:hover{
    color: #FFD700;
}

#view #back{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    background-color: #18181a; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

i set my `#view` element (which is the parent element) to height: max-content but it isn't setting the height, the height is still 0, but the width is maxed and as u can see, there are no other parent elements containing `#view`. I've changed the body's style to height: max-content as well but it ain't working

Comment: before u commet `display: none` is affecting it, no its not, because thats for my code part and im 100% sure it isn't the reason (in case u viewed my code before i edited it)

Comment: Your `#view` element does not have any content that could give it any height, because you positioned all child elements absolute.

Comment: yes because i want my layer to go ontop of all the other childs

Comment: But you positioned `#content`absolute as well …?

Comment: yea i did, should i not make it absolute?

Comment: yey it worked when i set pos relative for my content